# Tensorflow Conv2D работа с черно белыми изображениями

Tags: model, keras, tensorflow

Как обрабатывать черно белые изображения через `Conv2D`?

Если задать один канал `input_shape=(w, h, 1)`, то при экспортирование в Tensorflow model на этапе предикшна произойдет ошибка

> { "error": "Fused conv implementation does not support grouped convolutions for now.\n\t [[{{node conv2d/BiasAdd}}]]" }

Как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4D

```
input_shape= shape=[1] + (w, h, 1)
```